# How do I tell the Emscripten SDK where to find Node?

Tags: node.js, emscripten

Having trouble with the emsdk under Debian Jessie on an ODROID SBC. When I enter "emsdk list", it shows node is indeed installed:

> ```
>        node-4.1.1-32bit
>        node-4.1.1-64bit
>  *     node-8.9.1-32bit             INSTALLED
>        node-8.9.1-64bit
> ```

Yet when I enter **emcc -v** to check for warnings, I get:

> INFO:root:Checking JS engine
>   ['/home/jackalope/emsdk/node/8.9.1_32bit/bin/node'] failed. Check your
>   config file. Details: [Errno 8] Exec format error WARNING:root:cannot
>   check node version: [Errno 8] Exec format error INFO:root:(Emscripten:
>   Running sanity checks) CRITICAL:root:The JavaScript shell used for
>   compiling (['/home/jackalope/emsdk/node/8.9.1_32bit/bin/node']) does
>   not seem to work, check the paths in /home/jackalope/.emscripten

It looks like there's a binary file called "node" in the location it checks, but for some reason it is expecting a different format. I'm looking at the **.emscripten** file mentioned, but not sure what the path should be. It is as follows:

```
import os
LLVM_ROOT='/home/jackalope/emsdk/clang/tag-e1.37.36/build_tag-e1.37.36_32/bin'
NODE_JS='/home/jackalope/emsdk/node/8.9.1_32bit/bin/node'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT='/home/jackalope/emsdk/emscripten/tag-1.37.36'
EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER='/home/jackalope/emsdk/emscripten/tag-1.37.36_32bit_optimizer/optimizer'
SPIDERMONKEY_ENGINE = ''
V8_ENGINE = ''
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

Comment: Edited this question for clarity after I solved the issue. I can understand why it was down-voted, but sometimes you don't know quite how to phrase the question until you've found out just what the root problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe I found the problem: I needed to edit the **.emscripten** file and change

```
NODE_JS='/home/jackalope/emsdk/node/8.9.1_32bit/bin/node'
```

to

```
NODE_JS='node'
```