# Failing to locate node while linking

Tags: emscripten

Encountering "No such file" for node suggesting a path issue:

```
$ emmake make doc

make: ['make', 'doc']
[  0%] Linking CXX executable compile_Cwise_not_equal.js
/bin/sh: "/Users/amanda/development/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node": No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [doc/snippets/compile_Cwise_not_equal.js] Error 127
make[3]: *** Deleting file `doc/snippets/compile_Cwise_not_equal.js'
make[2]: *** [doc/snippets/CMakeFiles/compile_Cwise_not_equal.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/doc.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [doc] Error 2
```

following wasm generation:

```
225910 Oct 12 18:42 compile_Cwise_not_equal.wasm
```

The path in the above trace references a valid node executable:

```
$ /Users/amanda/development/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node

Welcome to Node.js v12.9.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

Located a prior question:

[How do I tell the Emscripten SDK where to find Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483622/how-do-i-tell-the-emscripten-sdk-where-to-find-node)

involving a similar problem involving an absolute path.  Attempted the proposed solution (although not clear on the rationale for the proposed solution) without success.  It is likely that I am missing something obvious.

My emscripten details:

```
$ source emsdk_env.sh

Setting environment variables:
EMSDK = /Users/amanda/development/emsdk
```

```
$ more /Users/amanda/.emscripten

LLVM_ROOT = '/Users/amanda/development/emsdk/fastcomp/fastcomp/bin'
BINARYEN_ROOT = '/Users/amanda/development/emsdk/fastcomp'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = '/Users/amanda/development/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten'
EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER = '/Users/amanda/development/emsdk/fastcomp/bin/optimizer'
NODE_JS = '/Users/amanda/development/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node'
TEMP_DIR = '/var/folders/gg/f3sw43zx0998_ngbf3s226_w0000gn/T'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

```
$emcc -v

emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 1.38.47
clang version 6.0.1 (/b/s/w/ir/cache/git/chromium.googlesource.com-external-github.com-emscripten--core-emscripten--fastcomp--clang 98df4be387dde3e3918fa5bbb5fc43e1a0e1daac) (/b/s/w/ir/cache/git/chromium.googlesource.com-external-github.com-emscripten--core-emscripten--fastcomp 6c7e775325067e33fa60611e619a8b987b6d0c35) (emscripten 1.38.31 : 1.38.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/amanda/development/emsdk/fastcomp/fastcomp/bin
shared:INFO: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...

Changed (CMakeCache.txt)

CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR:UNINITIALIZED="/usr/local/bin/node"
CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR:UNINITIALIZED=/usr/local/bin/node

resulting in wasm, js and out files....